# Как получить сообщение telegram bot aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я пишу телеграмм бота на `aiogram`, который должен при написании команды получать последнее сообщение, написаное пользователем.
Как можно это сделать?

Comment: обыкновенный echo bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types.base import String

API_TOKEN = 'token'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    try:
        global mes
        if message.text != '/command':
            mes = message.text
        if message.text == '/command':
            await message.answer(mes)
    except:
        await message.answer('Напишите что-нибудь')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Если пользователь сразу введет /command, а до этого сообщений никаких не вводил, то ему напишется 'Напишите что-нибудь'. В остальных случаях отправляется последний вводимый текст

Answer (score 2):

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


API_TOKEN = 'my-api-token'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Да но при этом мне нужно что бы это было не просто когда приходило сообщение, а конкретно при написании команды

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    print(message.text)#Сообщение содержится в message.text
    await message.answer(message.text)
```

Comment: что нового привносит ваш ответ в сравнении с ответом от Jack_oS? изложите это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]

Comment: Тоже не увидел каких то существенных отличий с [ранее данным ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1249028).